# How do I configure a CMake build non-interactively?

Tags: cmake

My current CMake workflow for a new debug build is:

```
mkdir debug-build
cd debug-build
ccmake /path/to/sources
```

I see this: [image]

I press `c` to configure, then `t` to toggle advanced mode. It now looks like this:

[image]

I can now change, e.g. `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` to `Debug` or enable warnings by setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`, etc.

How do I do all this non-interactively, from a shell script?

Comment: Hm, instead of  `ccmake` you may run `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-Wall /path/to/sources`. What is wrong with that?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks. Do you want to make that an actual answer?

Comment: The answer of @Fred looks reasonable. I don't want to add a similar answer.

Answer (score 0):

`cmake` itself is non interactive.  With many variables to be set I find it easier to use the `-C <initial-cache>` option with a file that sets any special cache entries.  You can also build at the command line with `cmake --build .`.